# Move-ADObject Error Parent Object Uninstantiated

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I am getting the following error when trying to move a user from one domain to another in active directory

"Move-ADObject : The operation could not be performed because the object's parent is either unistantiated or deleted"

The topology is like this:
Domain 1, DC1 - (GC) - Move-ADObject is trigerred for testuser under this domain on this DC. This also happens to be the root dc of the forest
domain 2, DC2 - (GC) - This is the target dc and the domain is child domain of Domain 1

Can anyone help me with this error?

Answer (score 2):

Did you use the -targetserver parameter?

```
move-adobject -identity "CN=testuser,ou=source,dc=domain1,dc=com" -targetpath "ou=destination,dc=domain2,dc=domain1,dc=com" -targetserver "dc2.domain2.domain1.com"
```